# open port 8080 for listening

Tags: linux, tcp

How can I open 8080 port for listening?

In normal situation, I have tomcat7 that listens on port 8080.

> ```
>      sudo netstat -tanpu | grep ":8080"
> tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      7519/java
> ```

After that, I stop tomcat7 with `sudo service tomcat7 stop`. So, now 8080 port is closed.

I did `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT` to open it, but the port is not listening.

```
sudo netstat -tanpu | grep ":8080"
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:37064         TIME_WAIT   -
```

How can I open this port (8080) for listening for another application ( not tomcat)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are confusing two concepts.  Iptables handles access control for your networking.  When you accept input traffic with a destination of TCP port 8008 that you just means you are letting the internet send traffic to that port.  It has no effect on what, if anything, is listening on the port.

To listen on a port you need a program set up to do that.  In your original case, `tomcat` was that program.  You stopped it so now nothing is listening on that port.  To open it back up as a listener you need to start `tomcat`, or any other program that you want, to listen on that port.  What program you select to listen on that port is entirely dependent on what service you want to provide on that port.

The iptables commands don't affect whether or not your program is listening, it just affects whether or not traffic from the internet is allowed to talk to that program.

If you just want to open up a network port that dumps whatever is sent to it, the program you want is `netcat`.  The command

```
nc -l -p 8080
```

This will cause netcat to listen on port 8080 and dump whatever is sent to that port to standard output.  You can redirect its output to a file if you want to save the data sent to that port.  If you want anything more sophisticated than a raw data dump, you will need to determine what specific program(s) are capable of handling your data and start one of those instead.

Comment: I edited my question. I want to open the port 8080 for another application

Comment: @user15992 which application?  What do you want to do on that port?

Comment: I'm using Docker. I need to receive some information from the container on port 8080

Comment: @user15992 with what program do you want to receive that information?  e.g. what kind of information is it?

Comment: @user15992 see my edit for a `netcat` example.  It may or may not be suitable for you, but I can't provide a better answer without more detail from you.

Comment: [The manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) states this about `-l`: "-p: It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -l option".

Answer (score 3):

You do not open a port.  You run a program, and the program listens for connections on a port.  So you need to ensure that no other programs are listening to port 8080, then you need to configure your program to listen to port 8080, and then you need to run your program.

Answer (score 1):

An application (such as tomcat) opens a port; once you stop that application, the port is closed. To open it again, you must (re)start an application that opens that port. You might `sudo service tomcat7 start`, for example.